# Run a bunch of tasks concurrently only when a certain condition is met?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, concurrency, simulation

This question is more about a design pattern than a language related question.

Let's say my problem is the following. Simulate a controlled system, with three main groups of tasks that run in an infinite loop:

- actuators: they are several and completely uncoupled
- dynamics: it shall run after actuators complete their run
- sensors: they are several, completely uncoupled and shall run after physical model task is completed

Actuators' and sensors' tasks can be run in parallel.

For example, in pseudo-cpp:

```cpp
class GenericActuator
{
  virtual void step() = 0;
}

class Actuator1 : GenericActuator
{
  void step() override;

  // other methods
}

class Actuator2 : GenericActuator
{
  void step() override;

  // other methods
}

class GenericSensor
{
  virtual void step() = 0;
}

class Sensor1 : GenericSensor
{
  void step() override;

  // other methods
}

class Sensor2 : GenericSensor
{
  void step() override;

  // other methods
}


int main()
{
  while (true)
  {
    runConcurrentlyStepForActuators(); // this shall block until all actuators' step() methods are done
    runDynamics(); // this is a single function, not a problem
    runConcurrentlyStepForSensors(); // this shall block until all sensors' step() methods are done
  } 
}
```

Is there any design pattern that solves problem like this, in which there are groups of threads that can be run concurrently but only if a certain condition is met and stop until the condition is met again? Is there any (possibly) C++ feature I can use to get this behaviour? Is this a bad design? In such a case, how can I approach the problem in a more elegant way?

Comment: That's [`std::barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier) or [`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch) use case. Whether this is a good architecture or not, we cannot tell. It sounds like a reasonable premise if both actuators and sensors take non-trivial amount of time to perform their task (if it's quick, adding multithreading increases code complexity unnecessarily and can potentially make execution slower).

Comment: *"run concurrently but only if a certain condition is met"* -- How does this "certain condition" fit into your situation? From your description and code, it appears that you *unconditionally* run the actuators and sensors in parallel when their time comes.